# Android string format with xliff:g inserts a blank space

Tags: android, android-resources

I think I found a bug with how Android parses strings with `<xliff:g>` tag.

Here are two example strings:

```
<string name="test">
    blah blah %1$s %2$s blah blah ...
</string>
```

This turns out to be "blah blah $argument1 $argument2 blah blah ...". Good!

The same string with `<xliff:g>` tags:

```
<string name="test">
    blah blah 
    <xliff:g id="firstArgument" example="ha">%1$s</xliff:g> 
    <xliff:g id="secondArgument" example="haha">%2$s</xliff:g> 
    blah blah ...
</string>
```

This turns out to be... " blah blah $argument1 $argument2 blah blah ...". WHY IS THERE A BLANK SPACE IN FRONT OF THE STRING?

Anyone know any work-arounds besides the obvious

```
<string name="test">blah blah 
    <xliff:g id="firstArgument" example="ha">%1$s</xliff:g> 
    <xliff:g id="secondArgument" example="haha">%2$s</xliff:g> 
    blah blah ...
</string>
```

Since that just looks hella ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue. If you have any whitespace between the start/end string tags, it will be included in the final string. In your example above, the end of the string will also include a space after the '...'

If you wanted to avoid the extra trailing space:

```
<string name="test">blah blah 
    <xliff:g id="firstArgument" example="ha">%1$s</xliff:g> 
    <xliff:g id="secondArgument" example="haha">%2$s</xliff:g> 
blah blah ...</string>
```

Surprisingly the documentation doesn't make any mention of this:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html

It may be worth filing a bug to report this.